# How to show the Unreal screen in Android's subview?

Tags: android, android-studio, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I want to know how to show the Unreal screen on Android's subview.

I want to show the Unreal screen in subView for Android-based projects.

I want to put it in a project created by a new project through Android Studio. The start consists of Android native code, and several menus were all created using JetPack api.

Here, I want to configure the bottom with Android UI and the top with an Unreal screen. Or, if you press the start button for UNREAL screen, I want to render the screen where the entire screen is UNREAL screen.

These two things should possible.

I knew how to do Unity. Unity knows what is possible. Is Unreal possible? If possible, can I get help with the guide links such as documents and videos?

Answer (score 1):

Try this as I assume that you have already added the Unreal Engine Viewport Client plugin to your project and that you have added a LinearLayout with the id

```
import com.epicgames.ue4.ViewportClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ViewportClient mViewportClient;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create the Android View to display the Unreal Engine Viewport
        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);

        // Add the Android View to the layout
        LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        layout.addView(mSurfaceView);

        // Create the Viewport Client and associate it with the Android View
        mViewportClient = new ViewportClient();
        mViewportClient.SetViewport(mSurfaceView);

        // Configure the rendering settings for the Viewport Client
        mViewportClient.SetResolution(1920, 1080);
        mViewportClient.SetCameraPosition(0, 0, 1000);
        mViewportClient.SetPostProcessingEnabled(false);

        // Start the rendering loop for the Viewport Client
        mViewportClient.Start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Stop the rendering loop when the activity is destroyed
        mViewportClient.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Where can I find a guide document to create something like Unreal Bundle File (build by unreal developer) to add to the Android Project to be loaded in the ViewPortClient above code? 
I cannot find document..... I'm looking for a document here... 
[link](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/android-support-for-unreal-engine/) and I can't vote because my reputation is less than 15.

Comment: For example, how to import "import com.epicames.ue4.ViewportClient;" from an Android project open in an Android studio.

Comment: Even though this was discussed a few years ago, this still seems to be relevant it can be done using Unity. But what about Unreal? Has anyone found a way to achieve this?